# how to generated C or C++ source file into a temporary assembly with NDK r8b

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk, makefile

my code has some problem in compiler's optim, i want to see the a temporary assembly code of my c++ files. how to config the android.mk file?

if i use

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -S
```

the compiler error! and output:

```
f:/codes/eclipse/android-ndk-r8b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6.x-google/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe:./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/sunred/SunRedVersion.o: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
f:/codes/eclipse/android-ndk-r8b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6.x-google/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe:./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/sunred/SunRedVersion.o:1: syntax error
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libsunred.so] Error 1
```

and no any assembly code generate.

if i use

```
myasmfilter :=  $OBJS_DIR/SunRedVersion.S.original $OBJS_DIR/SunRedVersion.S $OBJS_DIR/SunRedVersion.o

    LOCAL_FILTER_ASM := myasmfilter
```

it out put

```
AsmFilter      : sunred <= SunRedVersion.s

myasmfilter ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/sunred/SunRedVersion.s ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/sunred/SunRedVersion.filtered.s
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, myasmfilter ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/sunred/SunRedVersion.s ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/sunred/SunRedVersion.filtered.s, ...) failed.
make (e=2): 系统找不到指定的文件。(system can't find the file)

make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/sunred/SunRedVersion.filtered.s] Error 2
```

it can find a assembly code ,no anyother files.  if i change other cpp file,it still output the first make file's assembly code.

somebody know how to write **LOCAL_FILTER_ASM filter**? can give me a example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ndk-bulid** transparently runs **make** with all its parameters. So, you can use it as follows:

```
ndk-build obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/sunred/SunRedVersion.o LOCAL_CFLAGS=-S V=1
```

... for any C file you want to investigate. Or even specify multiple targets on the command line.

Comment: OH~~~Year! i add the cmd to eclipse C++ builder config.it works but how to write it in android.mk?

Comment: I find the problem,my code is c++ src,i use LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -S in android.mk,it can generate all temporary assembly code,but it still report. have some idear about LOCAL_FILTER_ASM? how to use the keyword? obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/sunred/SunRedVersion.o: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
ld.exe:./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/sunred/SunRedVersion.o:1: syntax error
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libsunred.so] Error 1

Comment: The purpose of myasmfilter is different. See the description of LOCAL_FILTER_ASM in docs/ANDROID-MK.TXT for more details. This can be useful for certain kinds of obfuscation tasks. And why would you change your Android.mk file for such task? Much more natural to run ndk-build manually from command line with special parameters when specific assembly file is needed.

Comment: i read the doc,but it no idear about how to write myasmfilter
when i write the follows it compile error!
myasmfilter :=  $OBJS_DIR/SunRedVersion.S.original $OBJS_DIR/SunRedVersion.S $OBJS_DIR/SunRedVersion.o 

LOCAL_FILTER_ASM := myasmfilter

Comment: myasmfilter should be a shell command (executable, or bash script, or maybe even .bat) that receives assembly file on stdin and produces asm file on stdout. It can be used to mangle some symbols to make the codeharder to disassemble.